# Clicking a TextView in a Custom ListView goes for ListView's ItemClick function

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview, baseadapter

I am Having a Custom `ListView` containing a number of `TextView`s, an `ImageView`, etc. which are loaded dynamically and the `TextView`s differs in number for each listitem. I am using `OnClickListener()` for the `TextView`s and that is where I get a problem.

Actually I was using `Button`s previously before using `TextView`s. The reason I switched to `TextView`s is that the `Button`s  acquire more space which is not sufficient for a listitem. Also the `TextView` has `OnClickListener()` which is similar to `Button` and the `TextView`s acquire less space compared to `Button`s.

Coming to the Problem when I click a `TextView` inside a listitem, Lets say I have 3 `TextView`s one of those `TextView`s work fine while the other two calls  `OnItemClickListener()` instead of calling `textView.OnclickListener()`

**Note:** My Custom `ListView` Activity extends `BaseAdapter` and all the functionalities are done inside `getView()`. I am not able to use `listview.setOnItemClickListener()` since its not working and I don't know why. Instead I am using `convertView.setOnclickListener()`

Any suggestions? or Am I doing any thing wrong?

Here is the code:

CustomListItemsAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;
private int selectedNetWeightPosition=0; 
private String netWeightValuesPerItem="";

private String[] arrayOfNetWeights;
private String[] arrayOfSelectedNetWeights;

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomListItemsAdapter(ListItemsActivity listItemsActivity, String[] itemNetWeight, String[] itemNetWeightSelected) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    context=listItemsActivity;
    arrayOfNetWeights = itemNetWeight;
    arrayOfSelectedNetWeights = itemNetWeightSelected;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arrayOfNames.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    private TextView netWeightText;
    private LinearLayout netWeightLayout;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;     

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_content, parent, false);
        holder.netWeightLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemNetWeightLayout);

        String[] data=arrayOfNetWeights[position].split(",");
        for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++)
        {
            holder.netWeightText = new TextView(context);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams netWeightTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            netWeightTextParams.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);
            holder.netWeightText.setLayoutParams(netWeightTextParams);
            holder.netWeightText.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            holder.netWeightText.setId(j);
            holder.netWeightText.setText(data[j]);
            holder.netWeightText.setTag(position);
            holder.netWeightText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.netweight_default);
            holder.netWeightText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            if(j==selectedNetWeightPosition)
            {
                holder.netWeightText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.netweight_clicked);
            }
            holder.netWeightLayout.addView(holder.netWeightText);
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    OnClickListener netWeightTextListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String[] data=arrayOfNetWeights[position].split(",");
            for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                int pos = v.getId();
                if(pos!=i)
                {
                    TextView netWeightTextUnClicked = (TextView) holder.netWeightLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    netWeightTextUnClicked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.netweight_default);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextView netWeightTextClicked = (TextView) holder.netWeightLayout.getChildAt(pos);
                    netWeightTextClicked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.netweight_clicked);
                }
            }   
        }
    };

    String[] data=arrayOfNetWeights[position].split(",");
    for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++)
    {
        holder.netWeightText.setOnClickListener(netWeightTextListener);
    }

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });   

 return convertView;
 }
}
```

Comment: better post some code please

Comment: Do add your codes for the community to see and have a better grasp on how tackle your problem.

Comment: post your adapter class.

Comment: @Nisarg I have added the code

Comment: @McAwesomville code added

Comment: @SohailZahid, code added

Comment: @Joshua for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++)
    {
        holder.netWeightText.setOnClickListener(netWeightTextListener);
    } //  why did you do this !!

Comment: @Nisarg I did it for changing the background color for the clicked `TextView` and the other `TextView`s

Comment: I guess it causes error simply take onclick of textview and try it . dont take listener.

Comment: @Nisarg I tried your suggestion, No changes. Still its going to itemclick function

Comment: @Joshua after looking at what you want to achieve you should try using POJO class.it'd be easier

Comment: ok @Nisarg I ll try the POJO class and I ll update :)

Comment: @Joshua yea sure let us know if any issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want a click event on `TextView` inside `getView()` then use `ViewHolder` for declaring views and inside `getView()` create object of all views and then use `setTag()` and `getTag()` for `TextView`.